# How to upload files to the root of a Azure Blob Storage container without the file path

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

The code below is able to upload files in the specified directory `localPath` to an Azure Blob Storage container. The problem is that the files are not placed in the root of the container, but folders are created that match the file path defined by the `localPath` variable.

`string localPath = @"C:\example\path\to\files";`

The resulting blob container looks like this.

```
.
+-- example
|   +-- path
|       +-- to
|           +-- files
|               +-- file1.json
|               +-- file2.json
|               +-- file3.json
|               +-- file4.json
|               +-- file5.json
```

What changes are required to the code below so that the files are moved to the root of the container instead of within this folder structure that matches the `localPath`?

**Program.cs**

```
namespace AzureBlobStorageFileTransfer
{
    using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            ProcessAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private static async Task ProcessAsync()
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = null;
            CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = null;
            string storageConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("storageconnectionstring");

            if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(storageConnectionString, out storageAccount))
            {
                try
                {
                    CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                    cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("example");

                    BlobContainerPermissions permissions = new BlobContainerPermissions
                    {
                        PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                    };
                    await cloudBlobContainer.SetPermissionsAsync(permissions);

                    string localPath = @"C:\example\path\to\files";
                    var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(localPath, "*.json");

                    foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
                    {
                        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(currentFile);
                        await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(currentFile);
                    }

                }
                catch (StorageException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error returned from the service: {0}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "A connection string has not been defined in the system environment variables. " +
                    "Add a environment variable named 'storageconnectionstring' with your storage " +
                    "connection string as a value.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `Path.GetFileName(currentFile)` into `cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference` to accomplish this:

```
foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
{
    string currentFileName = Path.GetFileName(currentFile);
    CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(currentFileName);
    await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(currentFile);
}
```